# Locking access to remote DB from a freely downloadable app (that acces the DB)

Tags: authentication

If I want to publish a software that needs to interact directly with a remote database, I will have to put on the software all the required credentials and logic to have the access from the program itself. (No user identification required as it would be a public app and no intermediate servers)

With that software around "in the wild", with more or less difficulty someone can hack it and find the procedure to access the DB with the same rights.

Going more specific, the app could be some simple free game for mobile devices with  scoring and achievements in the remote DB.

What is a reasonable general strategy around this from a security point of view (if it makes any sense to go this route at all. Probably this question is so basic that I can't find a solution)

Comment: Do you have a means to identify/authenticate individual users/installs?

Comment: I am still at the first stages of design so don't have a clear idea yet. Anyway the would be a way to identify uniquely users or devices from the device itself either through a generic account or a unique hardware id (although always there's the possibility of a hacker getting into it)

Comment: Hmkay, the security you need would probably depend on how well you can authenticate your clients, what level of fraud you're willing to accept, and whether your clients are easily able to install custom apps made by potential fraudsters (e.g. whether mobile/desktop). You should at least ensure that you can rollback an individual client's actions if you suspect/identify cheating, and validate the legality of all client actions on the server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a security standpoint you should limit the attack surface you are exposing.
As with most security features you should use defense in depth and have several security features in place like:

- A web based API (like REST with JSON), being server over a TLS connection.
- Limit allows values to a small set. (highscore is only numbers between 0 and 999999 for example)
- Use Client side Certificates to limit abuse through simple means. (A determent attacker still can of course)
- Use nonce in your API to prevent replay attacks.

There are propably more out there but this should give you an idea.

Comment: And always implement stored procedures when possible. Do not allow raw queries to the DB.

Comment: I think that the cocept "Stored procedures" points to the actual solution for my case. Although the first DB engine candidate does not provide them (AWS DynamoDB), an intermediate web server accepting processing and serving specialised requests would be the way to have control in many senses. Either reacting to attacks, independence between app and database etc.